# how to resove smsSend() error in sl4a python

Tags: android, python, sl4a

i am using Android , i want to send sms using  this sl4a python code:
it is related to my project.

```
 import android
 droid = android.Android() 
 number = droid.dialogGetInput('Send SMS', 'Phone Number?').result
 message = 'Test SMS' 
 result = droid.smsSend(number, message)
```

it is working on android AVD but not in Android Phone...?

Comment: Do you get any error ? its hard to tell whats wrong when all you tell us is "not working" .

Comment: i dont get any error.