# Sending a text using qpython

Tags: python, sl4a, qpython

I have been trying to send a text message using sl4a in qpython

Here is my code:

```
import androidhelper

droid = androidhelper.Android()
droid.smsSend('phone number in here', 'message in here')
```

When I run it, nothing happens

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the source code of sl4a's sms facade is here: https://github.com/damonkohler/sl4a/blob/master/android/Common/src/com/googlecode/android_scripting/facade/SmsFacade.java

And the class it uses was deprecated long long ago. Android documentation is here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html

According to the documentation, the old class only works on GSM. I think that's why it works on virtual machines, but not on a real device(maybe CDMA). An older similar question without answer is here: 
[how to resove smsSend() error in sl4a python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998075/how-to-resove-smssend-error-in-sl4a-python)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I use Qpython.

But in old Qpython3(py3.2), I can use sl4a.Android module to send message.

Something like this:

```
import sl4a 
droid = sl4a.Android()
droid.smsSend("0044....","sms")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the android module as shown below with qpython3 :

```
from android import Android
droid = Android()

droid.smsSend("number", "msg")
```